# Dump cfquery sql with cfqueryparam values

Tags: coldfusion

I want to dump the sql that is executed. I know several ways to dump the sql however all the methods I know show the cfqueryparam as an ? in the sql. For example when i dump this query :

```
<cfset testid = 1>
<cfquery name="myVariable" result="myResults" datasource="#myDatabase#">
select id from myTable where id = <cfqueryparam value="#testId#">
<cfquery>
```

The output is:

```
select id from myTable where id = ?
```

I want to the output to be:

```
select id from myTable where id = 1
```

I tried the following:

```
<Cfdump var="#myVariable.getMetadata().getExtendedMetaData().sql#">
<Cfdump var="#myResults.SQL#">
```

Both didn't work.

Comment: If it's not production code, run the query without the queryparam tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of a native solution to obtain the executed SQL string *with* parameters included. Perhaps there is an underlying Java class that I am not aware of (I think there is one if you have debugging enabled).

You could otherwise take the `sql` and `sqlParameters` keys from the result struct and build it yourself. Not ideal in my opinion, but an option.

```
<cfset testid = 1>
<cfquery name="myVariable" result="myResults" datasource="#myDatabase#">
select id from myTable where id = <cfqueryparam value="#testId#">
<cfquery>

<cfset completeQuery = myResults.sql>
<cfloop index="element" array="#myResults.sqlParameters#">
    <!--- Test for numeric value to help format in the SQL string --->
    <cfset completeQuery = replace(completeQuery, "?", (isNumeric(element)) ? element : "'#element#'", "one")>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#completeQuery#">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your dump  var = "#myResults.SQLParameters#"

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/accessing-and-retrieving-data/getting-information-about-query-results.html

Comment: SQLParameters shows all parameters used in the query. Not the actual sql that is executed. I want the sql which is executed with the parameters included as shown in my example.